# can i make inteface in my xsd schema?

Tags: xsd, jaxb, unmarshalling

In my schema I have a base class called "TypeGroup" and a few classes that extend from it.
Every class has a member "value" with a different type.

In my program I got the "TypeGroup" class instance and I want to get the "value" from the 
the extension class.

I thought to make the member type "object" in the base class "TypeGroup" but I don't know how to do it.

I'd like some ideas to resolve my problems

thanks;
roi.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a schema and you want to generate the model as described in this question?  If so, do you need to generate the model or is it ok to modify the classes manually?